# tensor accents and sub-super-scripts

Tags: tensor

Tensor notation with subscript `i` and superscript `j` to the right of the `i`

```
${A_i}^j$              %  correct

${\tilde A_i}^j$       %  j is above i

${{\tilde A}_i}^j$     %  ditto
```

My question is not how to fix it:  `$\tilde A_i{}^j$`, 
but wherein the TeXBook it discusses this very strange occurrence.

The TeXbook --- similar to the Bible but provides solutions to the exercises.

Comment: `${{}\tilde{A}_i}^j$`

Comment: In the TeXbook, tensor notation is the subject of Exercise 16.6.  From that answer, I conclude that this is what is recommended: `$\tilde A_i{}^j$`

Comment: Sorry!  I didn't state the question quite correctly.  I am interested in plain TeX (the reason for the TeXbook).  I couldn't find why  $A_i^j$ works correctly but not $\tilde A_i^j$ and not ${\tilde A}_i^j$.  I agree that $\tilde A_i{}^j$ works - and makes good sense - (fortunately "tensor" is in the index).  But why does the "\tilde" change the behavior of the following superscript.  In Eijkhout's book he says: " Math accents can adapt themselves to the size of the accented expression: TEX will
look for a successor of an accent in the same way that it looks for a successor of a delimiter."

Answer (score 1):

In the *TeXbook*, tensor notation is the subject of Exercise 16.6. From that answer, I conclude that this is what is recommended:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\tilde A_i{}^j$

$R_i{}^{jk}{}_l$ -- from the \emph{\TeX book}, Exercise 16.6.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 0):

I have added two different options with tensor package and the code @egreg's comment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
${{}\tilde{A}_i}^j$ % @egreg's comment for example

$\tensor{\tilde{A}}{_i^j}$ % using `tensor` package
\end{document}
```

[image]